# "L'été dernier" or "en été dernier"?

Tags: prépositions, articles, indications-de-temps

"I went to France last summer."

Should this be translated as

> Je suis allé en France l'été dernier.

or

> Je suis allé en France en été dernier.

? I know that "in summer" is usually translated with "en été", but when there's a modifying adjective I'm not sure which is the correct translation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said before :

> Je suis allé en France l'été dernier.

You give a precise time indication : last year's summertime.

Some variations to answer better your concern :

- "Je suis allé en France en été." : means "during the summer season". You indicate the season only.
- <s>"Je suis allé en France en été dernier."</s> : this form is not used
- "Je suis allé en France en été l'an dernier." : is a possible combination. It indicates the same time as the chosen answer, but it is used to answer the question "Which year did you go to France in summertime?"

Answer (score -1):

Je suis allé en France l'été dernier

Comment: Avec une explication, ce serait mieux.